# Using **kwargs in a Python function

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Consider a method like the one below:

```
    def find_missing(self, **kwargs):
        if save == True:
            tmp = find_one_missing(self.data)
            tmp.to_csv(path)
        else:
            return find_one_missing(self.data)
```

What I am trying to achieve is the variables `save` and `path` to be `kwargs`, whereby the use can specify either

```
x.find_missing()
```

which will return the output of the `find_one_missing()` function, or alternatively the user can insert

```
x.find_missing(save=True, path=user_string_pathway)
```

and the output will be automatically saved to a location. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to use `kwargs["save"]` to access it (after checking to see if it's present).  
Similarly for `path`.

Comment: Another alternative is to remove the keyword argument, and instead provide default values, e.g. `def find_missing(self, save=None, path=None):`  Then you could access the arguments normally.

Comment: Why are you using `**kwargs` at all? That's something you use if you want your function to accept *arbitrary* keyword arguments. It looks like you're looking for default values and/or keyword-only argument syntax.

Comment: Also, interface suggestion: consider using a single `save_to` argument, or just removing the `save` argument and keeping `path`. You don't need two separate arguments, and using one argument avoids problems with people passing inconsistent arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call:

```
find_missing(save=True, path="/path/...")
```

Access the value using kwargs['save'] and kwargs['path']

```
def find_missing(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['save'] == True:
            tmp = find_one_missing(self.data)
            tmp.to_csv(kwargs['path'])
        else:
            return find_one_missing(self.data)
```